# Javascript Multiple IMG Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, onclick

I'm using a button onclick and Image array to show a 1 image, and then a third image. I want to have several images do this next to each other. The code works fine with one..But when I try to add another it goofs up. I'm very new to Javascript so do not know what the problem is.

```
<button onclick="Suit()" class="button">
<img id="IMG1" src="suit.png" class="suit" width="300" height="260">
</button>



 <script>
 img_array= new Array('suit.png','suitwrong.png','suittry.png');
 i=0;
 function Suit()
    {
      i++;
     document.getElementById("IMG1").src=img_array[i];
     if(i==img_array.length-1) {
     i=-1;

    } 

  }
  </script>
```

I basically want to have x3 of this code (3 image click arrays). Happy to put it in a seperate .js file if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

is this really the script? if it is so try changing something like put var everytime you declare a js variable. and practice more math and logic in arrays and loops.
btw try this

```
<button onclick="Suit()" class="button">
<img id="IMG1" src="suit.png" class="suit" width="300" height="260">
</button>

<script>
 img_array= new Array('suit.png','suitwrong.png','suittry.png');
 i=0;
 function Suit()
    {
      i++;
     document.getElementById("IMG1").src=img_array[i];
     if(i==img_array.length) {
     i=i-img_array.length;
    } 

  }
  </script>
```

now try to add another picture in your array

Comment: I may not have made myself clear, I don't want to add more pictures to the array, I want to add an entirely new button onclick function which has the same effect. With this code I get broken image links when I click more than once, any ideas?

Comment: I still didn't get it maybe. do you want to add button? so when you click you will have 2 button is that your point?

Comment: idont know if this will work but just to give you another idea<button onclick="Suit(1)" class="button">
<img id="IMG1"...
</button>
<button onclick="Suit(2)" class="button">
<img id="IMG2"...
</button>
<button onclick="Suit(3)" class="button">
<img id="IMG3"...
</button>
 <script>
 img_array= new Array('suit.png','suitwrong.png','suittry.png');
 i=0;
 function Suit(i)
    {
      /*i++;*/
     document.getElementById("IMG"+i+"").src=img_array[i];
     /*if(i==img_array.length-1) {
     i=-1;*/

    } 

  }
  </script>